# Passing data from Map Annotation to a detail view controller SWIFT 3

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, swift3, mkannotation

I'm having heaps of trouble trying to figure out how I can present my detail view controller from a pin map annotation in my map view controller. When I click the detail disclosure button, it will take me to the detail view controller, but no data will be passed. It's just the basic layout I made in storyboard.
In the annotation, [I only have the a title, subtitle, and location coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12DVN.png). But in my detail view controller I have more than 15 different data.

How do I present it so that when I click on a map annotation, it will take me to its respective detail controller with all of the data, not just the data from the Annotation class.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is my part of my MapViewController

```
// 1
@objc(mapView:viewForAnnotation:) func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    if let annotation = annotation as? Annotations {

        let reuseID = "pin"

        var view: MKPinAnnotationView
        if let dequeuedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseID)
            as? MKPinAnnotationView { // 2
            dequeuedView.annotation = annotation
            view = dequeuedView
        } else {
            // 3
            view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseID)
            view.canShowCallout = true
            view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            view.calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -5, y: 5)
            view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton.init(type: .detailDisclosure) as UIButton
        }
        return view
    }
    return nil
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
        print(view.annotation?.title)
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "moreDetail", sender: self)
    }

}


func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "moreDetail") {
        // pass data to next view
        let destViewController:PancakeHouseViewController = segue.destination as! PancakeHouseViewController
        destViewController.viaSegue = (sender as! MKAnnotationView)
    }
}
```

And my .viaSegue connects with my detail view controller called PancakeHouseViewController

```
class PancakeHouseViewController: UITableViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

var viaSegue = MKAnnotationView()

@IBOutlet weak var addressLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
@IBOutlet weak var detailsLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var priceGuideLabel: UILabel!
```

And this is the Class "Annotations"

```
class Annotations: NSObject, MKAnnotation {

var title: String?
var subtitle: String?
var latitude: Double
var longitude: Double

var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
}

init(latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
    self.latitude = latitude
    self.longitude = longitude
}
```

}

Comment: you can pass data in prepareForSegue

Comment: Yes thats true, but I have no idea what to do with .viaSegue. When I try to pass in .nameLabel instead of .viaSegue, it says that it's not of the type MKAnnotationView. How would I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

add a new dictionary in your pancakeHouseVC class, you'll be using this to pass the data

```
class PancakeHouseViewController: UITableViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

 var viaSegue = MKAnnotationView()
 var dataDict:[String:String]
```

2. In your prepareForSegueMethod

   ```
    func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)        {
   if (segue.identifier == "moreDetail") {
   // pass data to next view
   let destViewController:PancakeHouseViewController = segue.destination as! PancakeHouseViewController
   destViewController.viaSegue = (sender as! MKAnnotationView)
   // set your data here in dataDict
   destViewController. dataDict = ["name":"add name"]
     }
   }
   ```